# Submenu not displayed in Laravel Voyager

Tags: laravel

In the controller, I pull the menu from the base:

```
$my_menu = menu('application_menu', '_json');
```

The menu is picked up normally, but except for sub-items (where parent_id! = NULL). That is, the second-level menu items are not pulled up. Why? Who faced this? How to solve? Thank you.

Comment: Clarifications. After a lot of testing, I saw that the sub-items are displayed fine. The problem arises when I try to translate like this: menu ('application_menu', '_json') -> translate($locale)

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in the comment of the question, the problem wasn't really that menu('application_menu', '_json') doesn't return child menu items. In fact it returns (when I asked the question I didn't notice it for the following reason). When I tried to retrieve the translated values ​​of menu items via menu ('application_menu', '_json')->translate($locale), in this situation, the sub-items were not taken. I have tested on both client side and server side. There may be some problem with the Voyager API.

I had to work around this problem by creating a menu table model, making a request for menu_id and then supplying the translation:

```
$my_menu = menu_items::select('id', 'title', 'icon_class', 'url', 'parent_id', 'order')
                        ->where('menu_id', 2)
                        ->orderBy('order')
                        ->get()
                        ->translate($locale);
```